# creating multiple executable files within a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My project has three .cs classes currently. Two of the classes are for two separate interfaces that I want to be linked to two separate executables when I build it. The third .cs file holds all their shared methods and variables (which includes the majority of the program)

What's the best way of implementing this? the opening/closing of one shouldn't effect the other.

Comment: Why not using 3 different solutions?

Comment: or 3 different project types referencing the ones needing referencing?

Comment: @varocarbas The majority of the code is the part that needs to be shared between the two executable.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I can reference methods from an outside project/solution?

Comment: not sure what you mean - perhaps the question is not clear or I am misunderstanding. you can add project references, or assembly references, in your project in solution explorer (right click project > add reference and choose the assembly/project reference you want to add to access those methods/properties exposed in that assembly).

Comment: If you have lots of code in common between various executables, you might put it into a common class in an external file (a DLL, for example); or just copy all the code over and over. But how you expect to deal with a solution having various executables? How would you do the debugging, in 4 dimensions? (LOL). There are surely options and alternatives to set up a complex solution linking different projects, but at the end everything is the same (and simple, classical, solid approaches tend to work pretty well): you will have to deal with as many projects as programs.